# 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'max_col'

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I have used the max_col attribute numerous times in other projects, but keep getting the error `'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'max_col'`

I'm especially confused because I use max_row right above it, with no error. I checked the documentation, and max_col still seems to be correct?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# excelToCSV.py - Converts all excel files in a directory to CSV, one file
# per sheet

import openpyxl
import csv
import os

for excelFile in os.listdir('.'):
    #Skip non-xlsx files, load the workbook object.
    if excelFile.endswith('.xlsx'):
        wbA = openpyxl.load_workbook(excelFile)
        #Loop through each sheet in the workbook
        for sheet in wbA.worksheets:    #Note: changing wb to wb.worksheets
            sheetName = sheet.title
            sheetA = wbA.get_sheet_by_name(sheetName)
            # Create the CSV filename from the excel filename and sheet title
            excelFileStripped = excelFile.strip('.xlsx')
            csvFilename = excelFileStripped + '_' + sheetName + '.csv'
            # Create the csv.writer object for this csv file
            csvFile = open(csvFilename, 'w', newline='')
            csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
            # Loop through every row in the sheet
            maxRow = sheetA.max_row
            maxCol = sheetA.max_col
```

Comment: Thank you, I was looking at the parameters for ```iter_rows``` above it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attribute is `max_column` not `max_col` ([official documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.max_column))