# Using openpyxl max_col as a max parameter in my for loop is breaking my code, what can I replace this with? Edit: I fixed it

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl with python 3.8.3 in pycharm to retrieve information from an excel spreadsheet. I'm using a for loop in order to search all of a row for a specific name. Here is my code:

```
 for i in range(1, ws.max_col):
        column_cell = ws.cell(column=i, row=todays_row)
        # print(column_cell)
        if ws[column_cell].value == recipient:
            cells_with_name.append(str(i))
```

If there is more that would be helpful, I can add more. I have declared column_cell previously as a global variable, so I don't believe that to be the problem. The error code states that ws.max_col is not a thing. I tried replacing it with ws.max_column but that gave a longer error saying basically the same thing. I am new to python, so I there may be something obvious I have missed. Thanks!

(One last thing, this all takes place in a function, I don't know if that matters, though.)

Edit: Here is my error code, I don't know if this helps:

```
  File "D:/Users/MyUse/PycharmProjects/inpyscheduler/mainEmail.py", line 25, in create_message
    ws_max_col = ws["max_column"].value
  File "D:\Users\MyUse\PycharmProjects\inpyscheduler\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 286, in __getitem__
    min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(key)
  File "D:\Users\MyUse\PycharmProjects\inpyscheduler\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\cell.py", line 135, in range_boundaries
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: max_column is not a valid coordinate or range
```

Edit 2: Here is my new code:

```
    for i in range(1, ws.max_column+1):
        column_cell = ws.cell(column=i, row=todays_row)
        # print(column_cell)
        if ws[column_cell].value == recipient:
            cells_with_name.append(str(i))
```

And here is my error:

```
  File "D:/Users/MyUse/PycharmProjects/inpyscheduler/mainEmail.py", line 34, in create_message
    if ws[column_cell].value == recipient:
  File "D:\Users\MyUse\PycharmProjects\inpyscheduler\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 286, in __getitem__
    min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(key)
  File "D:\Users\MyUse\PycharmProjects\inpyscheduler\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\cell.py", line 133, in range_boundaries
    m = ABSOLUTE_RE.match(range_string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Again, sorry if this is formatted weirdly, I'm new to both python and Stackoverflow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56352949/worksheet-object-has-no-attribute-max-col

Comment: You should include the error message in this kind of question,

Comment: @CharlieClark I added the error message! Thank you!

Comment: This is because you are trying use the a cell object for a lookup instead of a coordinate. But if you already have the cell object there is no need for a lookup. Just look at its `.value`. I suggest you work your way through the openpyxl tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that you were using the parameter `max_column` in an incorrect format.

It's `worksheet.max_column` not `max_col`.

eg:

```
for row in range(1, ws.max_row+1):
    for col in (1, ws.max_column+1):
        cell = ws.cell(row=row, column=col)
        print(cell.value)
```

And when u wanna get a cell value ,pls use `cell.value` not `ws[cell].value`,

or `ws['A1'].value` also works well.